# Exim not seding out mail, getting errors

Tags: exim

I dont know for how long, but just today I realized that exim is not sending out any mail. I tried restarting exim, nothing. Then i restarted the box, and still getting errors. I do not know why it is not sending. I cleared the mail queue, but that didnt do anything.. i dunno if that had anything to do with it but i tried it anyway. After clearing the mail queue i sent a message and went back to the mail queue and it cant be delivered, this is the error i get:

```
root@srv21:/etc/exim4# exim -qff
2012-07-31 14:56:32 1SvrdZ-0000gb-4h failed to expand condition "${perl{check_limits}}" for lookuphost router: Undefined subroutine &main::check_limits called.

2012-07-31 14:56:32 1Sw5eA-0004ZT-4p failed to expand condition "${perl{check_limits}}" for lookuphost router: Undefined subroutine &main::check_limits called.

2012-07-31 14:56:32 1Sw9t7-0006LJ-KF failed to expand condition "${perl{check_limits}}" for lookuphost router: Undefined subroutine &main::check_limits called.

2012-07-31 14:56:32 1Sw5eO-0004Zd-79 failed to expand condition "${perl{check_limits}}" for lookuphost router: Undefined subroutine &main::check_limits called.

2012-07-31 14:56:32 1SwApL-0006eu-Tv failed to expand condition "${perl{check_limits}}" for lookuphost router: Undefined subroutine &main::check_limits called.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is evidently an error inside exim.conf. seems like you have to rewrite your perl conditions OR when installing exim you did not indicate that you would be using perl conditions (which is a prerequisite during make install)